# При обновлении документа пропадает меню Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Доброго времени суток.

Разбираюсь с Google App Script, хочу создать кастомное меню ([вот документация](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createMenu(String)))

Вставил отсюда такой фрагмент кода:

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Автоматизация')
      .addItem('Выгрузка из банка', 'getLastRow')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Когда я запускаю скрипт из редактора скриптов, меню появляется и работает. Но при обновлении таблицы, оно исчезает. На просторах интернета я нашел несколько советов:

1. Станьте владельцем документа - но я уже владелец.
2. Проверьте права у скрипта - все дано, все в порядке.
3. Проверьте на других документах - тоже самое. Пробовал даже с другого аккаунта.

В общем, непонятная ситуация, прошу помочь или подсказать, в какую сторону копать.

UPD: Проблему решил созданием триггера через меню "Изменить - Триггеры текущего проекта - Добавление триггера", где указал параметры "При открытии" и функцию, которая и добавляет меню.

Comment: А у Вас в stackdriver есть какие-то данные по этой ошибке? Гугл что-то записывает? (в редакторе скриптов - меню ВИД - satckdriver Logging или ошибки Stackdriver)

Comment: Если ничего нет - то попробуйте вызов SpreadsheetApp.... обернуть try{}catch(err){Logger.log(err)} И тогда смотрите Stackdriver

Comment: Афтар, куда пропал?

Comment: Прошу прощения, вылетела задача из спринта не отвечал.

Ошибок никаких не было, даже после try-catch. 

Проблему решил созданием триггера через меню "Изменить - Триггеры текущего проекта - Добавление триггера", где указал параметры "При открытии" и функцию, которая и добавляет меню.

Comment: К сожалению, это неверное решение. Что пишет в Stackdriver? Так происходит со всеми скриптами? Возможно вы поймали редкий баг.